# CSS specific table

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have an HTML document where I have two different tables.  One is class Alpha and one is class Beta.  I want to assign this css to class Beta only...

```
td
{
border-style:solid;
border-top:thick double #ff0000;
}
```

I can not figure out how to assign this only to Beta.  Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Just apply the `.beta` class selector to the entire table and change your CSS code to apply a rule only to `td` decedents of `.beta` like this:

```
<table class="beta">
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

```
.beta td {
    border-style:solid;
    border-top:thick double #ff0000;
}
```

If you need to apply the rule to multiple elements within `.beta` simply add an additional selector like this:

```
.beta td, 
.beta th {
    border-style:solid;
    border-top:thick double #ff0000;
}
```

Qapla'!

Answer (score 14):

CSS lets you get specific with what elements rules are to be applied to. Just add this rule to the table.Beta td cell declaration and you're done.

```
table.Beta td 
{
    border-style:solid;
    border-top:thick double #ff0000;
}
```